# How do I divided the totals of a Case When by the Overall Total

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I have a code that breaks down a count by a case when....however I need a third column that takes the results of the case whens counts and divides it by the original total.....

How would I go about that?

Code is below

Basically I need

NumberOfDeals for each group/total number of deals

```
Select case when t_opportunity.opportunityID=yes.opportunityID 
            then 'Compliant' 
            else 'Non Compliant' 
       end as Compliance, 
       count(t_opportunity.opportunityID) as NumberOfDeals
from T_opportunity
left join (select t_O.opportunityId
           from t_opportunity T_O   
           inner join T_quote on T_O.opportunityID=t_quote.OpportunityId
           where t_quote.createddate<=(T_O.applicationsigneddate+7)
           group by t_O.opportunityID
           having count(t_quote.quoteID)>=3) yes 
  on T_opportunity.opportunityID=yes.opportunityID  
group by case when t_opportunity.opportunityID=yes.opportunityID 
              then 'Compliant' 
              else 'Non Compliant' 
         end
```

Thank You in Advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: What is wrong with current query? Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your `case` expression is returning a string.  I don't see how that is sensibly divided by any total.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, this might to the trick for you. Sample data and expected results are always helpful for data transformation questions though.

This assumes that if one opportunity has multiple matches in "yes" you want it counted twice (or N times). If that's not the case just shove a distinct in there.

```
SELECT compliance,
       COUNT(1) AS NumberOfDeals,
       COUNT(1)/Total_Count AS FieldYouAreAskingFor  -- Cast accordingly to get precision. 
  FROM (SELECT o.opportunityID, -- Shove distinct here. Or better rewrite as EXIST if you only want to count multiple matches once.
               CASE WHEN yes.opportunityID IS NOT NULL THEN 'COMPLIANT'
                    ELSE 'NOT COMPLIANT'
                END AS Compliance,
               SUM(1) OVER() AS Total_Count
          FROM T_OPPORTUNITY O
          LEFT
          JOIN (select t_O.opportunityId
                   from t_opportunity T_O   
                   inner join T_quote on T_O.opportunityID=t_quote.OpportunityId
                   where t_quote.createddate<=(T_O.applicationsigneddate+7)
                   group by t_O.opportunityID
                   having count(t_quote.quoteID)>=3
               ) yes 
            ON o.opportunityID = yes.opportunityID
       ) TMP
 GROUP
    BY TMP.Compliance,
       TMP.Total_Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to speculate that you intend:

```
select (case when t_opportunity.opportunityID = yes.opportunityID 
            then 'Compliant' 
            else 'Non Compliant' 
        end) as Compliance, 
       count(t_opportunity.opportunityID) as NumberOfDeals,
       count(t_opportunity.opportunityID) * 1.0 / sum(count(t_opportunity.opportunityID)) over () as Ratio
```

This uses a window function to calculate the total over rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, then your *opportunities* are "compliant" when they have at least 3 *quotes* created within a week (whatever that means, I think that you will understand that).

You can calculate the compliance within one query:

```
SELECT o.opportunityID,
  CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(q.quoteID) >= 3
    THEN 'Compliant'
    ELSE 'Not Compliant'
  END AS Compliance
FROM T_opportunity o
  LEFT OUTER JOIN t_quote q 
    ON o.opportunityID = q.OpportunityId
    AND DATEADD(day, 7, o.applicationsigneddate) >= q.createddate
GROUP BY o.opportunityID
```

In the next step, you can use this result as input for the grouping by `Compliance`:

```
WITH 
  OpportunityCompliance (opportunityID, Complicance) AS (
    SELECT o.opportunityID,
      CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(q.quoteID) >= 3
        THEN 'Compliant'
        ELSE 'Not Compliant'
      END
    FROM T_opportunity o
      LEFT OUTER JOIN t_quote q 
        ON o.opportunityID = q.OpportunityId
        AND DATEADD(day, 7, o.applicationsigneddate) >= q.createddate
    GROUP BY o.opportunityID
  )
SELECT 
  Complicance,
  COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDeals,
  1.0 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS Ratio
FROM OpportunityCompliance
GROUP BY Complicance
```